# Java Naming and Directory Interface adding self defined objects to directory

Tags: jndi

I have been trying to use JNDI to store my own predefined objects with  no success. I can get the jdbc object from the InitialContext and gain access to the connection object as shown below

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) context
     .lookup("jdbc/DataSource");
```

Now i need to know how to add my own objects to the jndi directory. Also please can you explain the architecture of jndi service

Comment: tag your question properly...

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how to add my own objects to the jndi directory.

Define them as named resources in your Tomcat context.xml, if you're using Tomcat, or the equivalent in whatever your servlet container is. If you mean to do this at runtime, you can't, that's not what it's for.

> Also please can you explain the architecture of jndi service

Far too broad a question for StackOverflow. Try the [JNDI Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/tutorial/index.html).